# How to get CustomerId from millions of records using Xquery in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

We have a large database, and I am supposed to get only CustomerId's from the entire database without compromising the performance. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to report all of the `CustomerId` values from a large database, then having some sort of backing index will be the fastest and most efficient. With an index, retrieving the distinct list of values from a lexicon with a functions such as:

- [`cts:values()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values) e.g. `cts:values(cts:element-reference('CustomerId'))` or `cts:values(cts:path-reference('/Customer/CustomerId'))`
- [`cts:element-values()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values)  e.g. `cts:element-values(xs:QName("CustomerId"))`

You could also create a [TDE](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE) that has a `CustomerId` field and retrieve the values with an [Optic](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI) query.

If you wanted to report the values without creating an index, then you could create a CoRB batch job to select the docs that have that element, return the value(s) from the process module, and write the values to an output file apply the [`EXPORT-FILE-SORT=ascending|distinct`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#EXPORT-FILE-SORT) option.